# PHP statement appearing on input text value, instead of the $_POST value

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have written an PHP form and tested it on WAMP server and was working fine.

When I got it into the webserver, the value tag on the input divs of the form, appeared on the page displaying the PHP code, instead of the $_POST value.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="contactos.php">
    <!-- FORM RESULT -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            <?php echo $result; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END FORM RESULT -->
    <!-- FORM NAME -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nome</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="O seu nome." value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : ''); ?>"/>
            <p class="text-danger">
                <?php echo '$errName';?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I can't really find out what's happening since it does work on WAMP server, but not on my webserver.

This is what I get on my webserver host.

PHP appearing on input form value tag picture

[image]
This is a fraction of the code since all the other inputs are a copy of the input div above to each other input.

Couldn't find any solution, so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `PHP` installed on server?? Are they configured properly?

Comment: and file extension is PHP or HTML??

Comment: what is the extension of your file on webserver, it seems that it is `.html` not `.php`. change extension to `.php`. Also check that php installed on your server or not?

Comment: you can not treat php pages as html, I think you are opening the pages on browser like html page. use localhost server to run this page and your problem is solved.

Comment: Went over all that already. It's a PHP file and I don't have access to php.ini on the host in question.

Comment: If it's `.php` then defiantly your server didn't have `php` installed or properly configured. Ask to the server provider to do the settings.

Comment: Ok, I believe there's a problem on my host. PHP ain't enabled, although it's part of the package I bought. I figured it out looking at your answers and it made sense. Tried phpinfo() and got no return. I'll close the question as soon as I have a confirmation from the host. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @HBT after solving the problem, post that as answer explaining the problem and what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Although all the website worked properly when installed on a local server, when I got the website online, I asked to enable a new hosting solution in order to have more capabilities and the website kept displaying the behavior explained on the question.

After testing the PHP functionality uploading a file with the phpinfo(), I realized that PHP was not active on my host.

This was an error on my host setup, which took some time to fix.

But the answer may be suitable to someone else who had similar problems. Check first if PHP is active on your webserver.

Just write a file and name it something like version.php and write the following in it:

```
<?php
     phpinfo();
?>
```

Upload the file to the root of your website.

Then go to your browser and enter www.yourwebsite.ext/version.php on the address bar.

If you see the PHP info panel, you have PHP installed and active on your webserver.

If you don't see this info, or just get a blank page, probably PHP is not active on your webserver.

Thank you for all the feedback.